# Shell login command not honored in later gradle plugin

Tags: docker, gradle, ibm-cloud, gradle-plugin

I need to use Transmode docker gradle plugin to push a docker image into IBM Cloud image repository. The push command is standard docker push, which is executed by the gradle plygin, but before that I need to execute a "ibmcloud login" command set:

```
task loginToIBMCloud (type: Exec) {
    group = 'docker'
    commandLine '/usr/local/bin/ibmcloud', 'login', '-a', 'https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net', '--apikey', 'MYAPIKEY'
    commandLine '/usr/local/bin/ibmcloud', 'cr', 'login'
    commandLine '/usr/local/bin/ibmcloud', 'cr', 'region-set', 'eu-central'
}
```

This command works OK but later when I gradle does the push, I get an error as docker command behaves as the previous login didn't occur:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildDockerAndPush'.
> Docker execution failed
  Command line [/usr/local/bin/docker push registry.eu-de.bluemix.net/eliza/tourism/mtp/ms/mtpms_weather:0.0.2b] returned:
  unauthorized: authentication required
```

This is the plugin task to build and push the image to repository:

```
task buildDockerAndPush(type: Docker) {
    group = 'docker'
    push = true;
    tagVersion = "${project.version}"
    exposePort(8080)
    addFile {
        from jar
        rename {'app.jar'}
    }
    entryPoint(['java', '-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom', '-jar', '/app.jar'])
}
```

Executing same comand series in shell works perfect. ibmcloud is OK, docker build is OK and docker push is ok. The image is correctly pushed to IBM repository which later works in a kubectl command.

So... how can I make the login executed in a previous Exec task in gradle still be valid in the second task.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "ibmcloud cr" command can replace almost entirely the docker command, so replacing that as docker command in the gradle plugin effectively builds the image in IBM Cloud. Not even "push" is needed, and not even local docker running is needed. This is not exactly the solution but solves the original problem of login+creating+pushing an image to IBM Cloud.

To replace the docker command just do this in your gradle build script (obviously with your correct path if different):

```
docker {
    dockerBinary "/usr/local/bin/ibmcloud rc"
}
```

And remember not including

```
push = true;
```

in the Docker type task as no push is now needed.